# get an input with certain name from iframe jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a form inside an iframe, now I want to get the input with certain name. The id of my iframe is "myFrame". I was able to take out the inputs inside the iframe by `$("#myFrame").contents().find("input")` but i want the input by name, so i did `$("#myFrame").contents().find("input[name=input_id]")` but with failure. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `input_id` is a **variable**, you need to concatenate the `input_id`:

```
$("#myFrame").contents().find("input[name='" + input_id + "']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried (using double quotes):

```
   $("#myFrame").contents().find('input[name="input_id"]')
```

and when you say that you took out the inputs with:

```
   $("#myFrame").contents().find("input")
```

did you check that the input you wanted was inside that collection?